# Error in contenttestingupdate.aspx while performing a Sitecore upgrade

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore8.1

I'm currently carrying out an upgrade to 8.1, but when running the contenttestingupdate.aspx admin page, it fails with the following error:

```
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: fieldNameTranslator
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.Linq.Solr.SolrIndexParameters..ctor(IIndexValueFormatter valueFormatter, IFieldQueryTranslatorMap`1 fieldQueryTranslators, FieldNameTranslator fieldNameTranslator, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts, IFieldMapReaders fieldMap, Boolean convertQueryDatesToUtc)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.LinqToSolrIndex`1..ctor(SolrSearchContext context, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchContext.GetQueryable[TItem](IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
 at Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.TestingSearch.GetAllTests()
 at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Upgrade.PostUpgradeRunner.GetTests()
 at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Upgrade.PostUpgradeRunner.Run(StepOptions steps)
 at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Upgrade.ContentTestingUpgrade.StartUpgrade(StepOptions options) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
 at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
 at (Object , Object[] )
 at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
 at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

All lucene configs are disabled, as it's using SOLR.

What could be the problem? Additionally, is this a step that could be skipped to continue with the upgrade?

Comment: You can skip this step if there is not A/B tests on your Sitecore instance.